# Spring display original value validation error

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have this form which i post to spring and I am trying to make it display the original value from the database before i posted the updated value whilst leaving the error message on the field if there is a validation error not the posted value. However nothing i do seems to work.

My post action looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateValues(@ModelAttribute("values") @Valid ValueList, Errors errors, RedircetAttributes redirectAttributes){

     if (errors.hasErrors()){
        return VALUES_VIEW;
     }
     //Do update stuff
     return VALUES_REDIRECT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the value coming in on the model to the value from the DB.  In your case, something like:

```
ValueList dbValueList = someService.getValueList();
valueListInModel.setSomeProperty(dbValueList.getSomeProperty());
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works if there is no error on the field. However spring continues to use the value posted if the value fails validation.